# Inserting data to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have tried to insert data to SQL Server 2000 database but in vain. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am using the below code that does not generate any error when i click on the button to insert but instead it inserts NULL as a string in the table for both column. Please help or just show me how to write a simple application that inserts some data to a database table. Thank you guys.

Below is the code I have so far managed to write and am using an sql datasource:

```html
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        My Test Insert
    </h2>
    <p class="style1">
        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p class="style1">
        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" style="text-align: center" 
            Width="260px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p class="style1">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="89px" />
    </p>
<p class="style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    <p class="style1">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO TblNames(FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TblNames]">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
            </InsertParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>

    </asp:Content>
```

The button click event:

```vb
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'If the page is valid, add the new product
        If Page.IsValid Then
            SqlDataSource1.Insert()

            'Display confirmation message
            Label1.Text = String.Format("Name {0} has been added to the database...", FirstName.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What error do you get, if any?

Comment: Hi I do not get any error the code executes when i click on the button and the alert fires successfully, funny enough if I examine the table i can see NULL inserted in both columns kindly help or give an alternative code i can try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Button1_Click without

```
 If Page.IsValid Then
```

?

Comment: Yes i have tried without the If page.IsValid but still it inserts NULL to the database table.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN library, your `InsertParameters` should be

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:FormParameter Name="FirstName" FormField="FirstName" />
    <asp:FormParameter Name="LastName" FormField="LastName" />
</InsertParameters>
```

In this code, you are telling the `Insert` parameters what their names and values will be.
Also, there is the option of `<asp:ControlParameter>` which also allows you to specify the name of the parameter and the controlid which will give you the value of the parameter.

Comment: I have tried this also but i see NULL inserted to the table overtime i click on the button. Kindly help